# Set Theory request for knowledge: Need criticism of where my logic is flawed with respect to the intersection of infinite sets. Example in post.

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Greetings fellow problem solvers! I'll start off by thanking anyone who takes the time to look over what I've done and redirect me. Now I'm not looking for solutions to this problem. My approach to learning this is by working out why something I have done is incorrect then refining it until I come to a proper solution.

The exercise: Produce an infinite collection of sets $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3},...$ with the property that every $A_i$ has an infinite number of elements $A_{j}\ \cap\ A_i = \emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{j} = N.$ Where N is the Natural Numbers

My solution to this is as follows.

$$A_1 = \{1, 2,..., n\}\\
A_2 = \{n+1, n+2, ..., k\}\\
A_3 = \{k+1, k+2, ..., m\}\\
A_i = \{m+1, m+2, ...\}$$
Where $n, k, m \in$ natural numbers.

Now to me, the above shows every $A_i$ has an infinite number of elements and  $A_{j}\ \cap\ A_i = \emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{j} = N.$ Where N is the Natural Numbers.

I feel like what I've done here is a horrible abuse of notation, at best. Worst case the logic doesn't even follow. Regardless I hope it gives enough insight into how I'm thinking about the intersection of these sets, for someone to help redirect my thought process.

Again I appreciate any feedback,

Comment: For $i=1$, $A_i$ has exactly $n$ elements.

Comment: I assume $n$, $k$ and $m$ are natural numbers. In that case, they are disjoint, but e.g. $A_1$ is not an infinite set if you mean the natural numbers from $1$ to $n$. Also you appear to only have finitely many sets specified, not infinitely many.

Comment: @gae Yeah, this is one of the things I'm struggling with here. I want to put limits on these sets so they make sense. I use n as some countable infinity. I am trying to fix my understanding. I was hoping this example would paint a better picture of how I'm thinking about these things. Possibly someone has a way for me to rethink what I'm doing.

Comment: @DanDoel I see what you're saying about the number of sets I've indeed put a limit of m on it. With that same logic, it follows that I've put limits on everything. What I'm failing to understand and have failed to understand for about 3 years now. Is how if set A1 has an infinite number of natural numbers, and A2 does as well, they will ever have an intersection that can be the empty set. I can't get behind this logic no matter how hard I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what exactly are $n,k,m$, etc. in the definitions of your sets? E.g. is $A_1=\{1,2,3\}$ ($n=3$), or $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ ($n=5$) or ...?

More importantly, contra your claim, each $A_i$ you've described is **finite** - e.g. if $n=6$ and $k=17$, then $A_2$ has only $17-6=11$ elements.

Since the $A_i$s have to be infinite, nothing like $\{a, a+1,..., b\}$ is going to work. Your $A_i$s have to be more complicated - essentially, they'll have to "interleave" with each other.

A good first step is to solve the following simpler problem:

> Find **two** sets $A_1,A_2$ such that $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$ but $A_1$ and $A_2$ each have infinitely many elements.

Don't try anything too fancy:

> For example, set $A_1=\{$evens$\}$ and $A_2=\{$odds$\}$.

Now how about **three** infinite, pairwise-disjoint sets - or more generally, $n$-many for $n$ finite?

> Try mod $3$, or mod $n$ more generally.

Getting **infinitely** many infinite, pairwise-disjoint sets is harder and the above idea doesn't immediately generalize. However, it should suggest some things to try, and there are various ways to get this to work. Here's one idea:

> Given a prime number $p$, let $Pow_p$ be the set of powers of $p$. How big is each $Pow_p$? If $p,q$ are distinct primes, what can you say about $Pow_p\cap Pow_q$? And finally, how many primes are there?

Comment: Oh wow, that's a Genuinely clever way to do this.  Thank you so much. for taking the time to write this out.

Answer (score 3):

Your sets are pairwise disjoint, and their union is $\Bbb N$, but **none** of them has an infinite number of elements: all of them are finite. Your $A_1$ has $n$ elements for some positive integer $n$; that is a finite number. Your $A_2$ has $k-n$ elements, again a finite number, your $A_3$ has $m-k$ elements, and so on.

There is the additional problem that you’ve not really explained how to keep going, though since the idea doesn’t work, this is perhaps of secondary significance. Still, it might be useful in the future to know how to write up the idea. Here is one way:

> Let $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence of non-negative integers such that $n_1=0$, and for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$A_k=\{m\in\Bbb Z^+:n_k+1\le m\le n_{k+1}\}\,.$$

Now let’s get back to the problem. Here is a sketch of one of the nicer ways to solve it.

- Show that for each positive integer $n$ there are unique non-negative integers $m$ and $k$ such that $n=2^k(2m+1)$.

Then for each non-negative integer $m$ let

$$A_m=\left\{2^k(2m+1):k\ge 0\right\}$$

and show that $\{A_m:m\ge 0\}$ satisfies the requirements of the problem.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelWalker: You’re welcome.